# Looping mod_rewrite and converting underscores to dashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are currently using the following rules in our .htaccess file:

```
# Convert URLs with underscores into hyphens (excluding any image files)
# Keep scanning the URL as long as there are two hyphens
RewriteRule       ^(/?.*[^/]*?)-([^/]*?-[^/]*)$ $1_$2 [N,QSA] 

# Replace last hyphen and do a permanent redirect (ending the rewriting operation)
RewriteRule       ^(/?.*[^/]*?)-([^/-]*)$       $1_$2 [L,QSA]
```

However, our web host is shutting down our site with the following complaint:

> On tracking this issue, we could found that rewrite FLAG of N in that
>   first rule is looping. That created the process to run for many hours
>   as endless loop and chewing up the resources of the server, as
>   spawning processes using several hundred MB of memory for each
>   process.

Do any of you mod_rewrite experts have a better way to do this?

We are simply trying to replace all underscores in our files with dashes for the URLs. We unfortunately are using software that cannot generate files with dashes in their filenames.

Much appreciated!

Thanks, Doug

Comment: Give at least one example of a typical incoming URL with underscores.  Guessing from your rules is not the best way to figure out a possible solution.

Comment: @faa Sure, here's two typical filenames in the root of our directory: books_posters_dvds_events.php  books_posters_dvds.html    They would be converted to   books-posters-dvds-events.php   and books-posters-dvds-events.html

Comment: Gotcha, sorry for not understanding your question:    http://www.example.com/fine_art_prints.php

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but I believe you could use `RewriteMap` to send all URLs with dashes to a simple external function that replaces all dashes with underscores. Here's the RewriteMap documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#mapfunc

Comment: @faa, we don't have any filenames containing more than 5 underscores total, if that makes any difference! Thanks in advance for any help with this...

Comment: Where is the file with the underscores inside the URL, it has a fixed position or can be in any place? Examples: `http://example.com/fine_art_prints.php` or `http://example.com/any/number/of/folders/fine_art_prints.php` or `http://example.com/folder/fine_art_prints.php/folder/`.

Comment: @faa there are no folders/directories or subfolders past the root level. All files are at the root level, for example     http://example.com/fine_art_prints.php